# How to block or set HTML5 Videos to autoplay using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I am writing a script and want to be able to set autoplay for any HTML5 Stream or Video. If even better, I would like to block or remove it temporarily from the site I am on. I will provide the inspected element as well.

If no one knows the above, is there way I can block a certain video id or class

```
<video id="still_video_object_html5_api" class="vjs-tech"
```

These are also the scripts that are unchanging to the HTML5 Live Stream

```
webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" autoplay="" tabindex="-1"
type="application/x-mpegURL"></video>
```

I am using: Python, Selenium Webdriver, & Chrome on Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

Tested with Chrome 67 and the C# version of the ChromeDriver, here's the code that allowed me to have YouTube videos autoplayed (whereas the default behaviour since Chrome 66 is to disable autoplay) :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");
IWebDriver browserDriver = new ChromeDriver(AppContext.BaseDirectory, options);
```

The Python API certainly has equivalent to the `AddArgument(string)` method.

Comment: In Python you can do:  

`from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`  
`option = Options()`  
`option.add_argument("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required")`  

in order to have the same behaviour as in C#